# Salesforce DX - The purpose of sandboxes

Tags: sandbox, salesforcedx, scratch-org

Given the current change of paradigm and the fact that we will be working with scratch orgs when working with SFDX, what will the role of sandboxes be?

On the one hand, they could make a staging environment for QA or UAT, but on the other hand, a scratch org could also fill that role, specially now that you can import data very easily with the `sfdx force:data:tree:import` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that, as you've guessed, they're mainly for User Acceptance/Integration testing and staging.

While it is true that you can import data, and add additional users to a scratch org, do you really want to do that with every iteration? Moreover, do your *users* want to use a new login to a new scratch org for each iteration? (my users would say no).

Sandboxes copy Users, *their profiles, roles, and permission sets* (amongst other things) from your production environment. There aren't any extra steps to set that up, and I'd say not having to reproduce those things is a win for you and being able to use their same credentials as prod (plus the `.<sandbox name>` on their usernames) is a win for your users.

In other words, I don't think the role of sandboxes really changes with SalesforceDX. They're still a non-production environment based on your production environment that offers a safe space to verify that changes will integrate with existing customizations and hammer out the kinks with profiles/roles.

Answer (score 3):

One thing a sandbox can (currently) do that a scratch org can't is behave as a full copy of production.

> Only [Full sandboxes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=create_test_instance.htm&type=0) support performance testing, load testing, and staging. Full sandboxes are a replica of your production org, including all data, such as object records and attachments, and metadata.

Trying to load all the required data into a scratch org might be possible, but a full sandbox would likely be quicker.

Note that there is a proposed [Winter ’18 Pilot - Org Shape for Scratch Orgs](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003GBx6q) that would help shape the scratch org like production. I'm not sure about the data though.

---

With scratch orgs being transient in nature by design they aren't a good fit for integrations either. I've got several projects where the QA environments of external systems need to reference a Salesforce org that isn't production. Sandboxes fill this role well.

Answer (score 2):

Sandboxes don't have any particular purpose in the DX life cycle. They are inferior to scratch orgs in almost all respects; sandboxes take longer to spin up, longer to activate, longer to populate data into, become stale faster, and for the larger sandboxes, have a very limited refresh rate (monthly).

That said, full copy sandboxes and partial copy sandboxes tend to be a bit better when you're dealing with things like troubleshooting existing problems because of bad data or large data volumes, training users using real-looking (but not live) data, and so on. They definitely have a purpose, but not in the sense of normal development and testing using DX.